My recent app update has been rejected for not adhering to the Google Play Developer Programme Policies
IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-533.png
Issue found: Violation of Broken Functionality policy
Your app contains content that isn’t compliant with the Broken Functionality policy.
App contains icon(s) or button(s) that are not responsive or do not return content.
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Version code 6: In-app experience: Please see attached screenshot IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-533.png
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:
Make sure to fix all broken experiences within your app. You can use the Pre-launch reports to check for app stability.
About the Broken Functionality policy
We don't allow apps that crash, force close, freeze, or otherwise function abnormally. Below are a few examples of common violations:
Apps that don't install
Apps that install, but don't load
Apps that load, but are not responsive
You can learn more about our policies by watching this video on tips to help you stay on the right side of Google Play policy.
Visit Google Play’s Academy for App Success to get contextual learning on this Google Play policy.
Action required: Submit an updated app for review
Here's what to do to help get your app on Google Play:
Make sure to read the applicable policies or requirements listed below:
Broken Functionality policy
Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to address the issue described above. You may also want to check your app's store listing for compliance, if applicable.
Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program Policies.
If you made changes to your app bundle, store listing, or APK, please sign in to your Play Console and submit the update(s).
here is my code can someone help me pass this step and bupish my app to the google play store
I passed 14 days of testing period where more than 22 users participated the testing process 1 out of the 22 had experience
d the issue, I tried my best but could not able to figure it out.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, SafeAreaView, Image, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert, ScrollView,Linking } from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import COLORS from './colors';

const ZAADSLSHSCREEN = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { params: { plant } } = route;
  const [lastNumber, setLastNumber] = useState('');

  const handlePress = async () => {
    if (!lastNumber.trim() || isNaN(lastNumber)) {
      Alert.alert('Invalid Input', 'Please enter a valid number.');
      return;
    }
    
    const code = `*377*323401*${lastNumber}#`;
    const encodedCode = encodeURIComponent(code);
    const url = `tel:${encodedCode}`;
  
    try {
      const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
      if (supported) {
        Alert.alert('Confirm Dial', 'Do you want to dial this USSD code?', [
          { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => {}, style: 'cancel' },
          { text: 'OK', onPress: () => Linking.openURL(url) }
        ]);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Unsupported Feature', "This device can't handle dialing the USSD code.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'An unexpected error occurred: ' + error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Image source={plant.img} style={styles.image} />
        <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Dollar ayaad heli doontaa</Text>
          <Text style={styles.description}>{plant.about}</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={setLastNumber}
            value={lastNumber}
            placeholder="Geli lacagta aad sarifanayso"
            keyboardType="numeric"
          />
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress} style={styles.buyBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.buyBtnText}>Sarifo</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
  },
  image: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flex: 2,
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf:'center'
    
  },
  detailsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.light,
    margin: 7,
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  description: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 22,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    marginVertical: 12,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    color: '#000',
    borderRadius: 50,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18
  },
  buyBtn: {
    backgroundColor: '#347dce',
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  buyBtnText: {
    color: COLORS.white,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  }
});
export default ZAADSLSHSCREEN;



Is there more information in IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-533.png ?

@kca I updated the question and added the IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-533.png please have a look and thanks for the help

I don't know the technology, but according the the error message, apparently your app tries to "dial some USSD code" ? And some devices may not be able to do that. Apparently the app isn't usable from this point on. If possible, you may try to handle this error, and provide an alternative route through the app. If that functionality is essential to your app, then the app is not suitable for being published to "arbitrary" people (I mean some people can use it, but some can't).

fyi App Store questions are off-topic here - see Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?
